# Computing Low-Rank approximation in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scikit-learn, matrix-factorization

Given a matrix M of dimensions nxn, how can I compute a low rank factorization such that M = L.T * L, where L is of dimensions kxn. So far I've only seen this done using SVD, which isn't exactly what I want because the method gives me M = U*S*V, and U.T != S*V, as opposed to (L.T).T == L.

Another alternative could be to use some form of optimization to find L, however it isn't straightforward because I've already tried several optimization methods from SciPy with the difference M - L.T * L under the frobenius norm, and so far I haven't been successful.

**Edit:** I forgot to add that by using scikit's Non-Negative Matrix Factorization class I'm able to achieve this partially by passing L and L.T as candidate matrices for the optimization. However, my matrix M is not non-negative, therefore this method doesn't work for me.

Comment: you say **"what's the best way to..."** but what do you mean by **best**?  Do you mean fastest to execute?  Lowest in complexity?  Easiest to read and understand?  Easiest to code? -- Also you said **" I tried `x' but it isn't what I want"** What's wrong with it?  What would be what you want?  Seems like SVD would be a great way to find the factorization.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I improved the question to address your suggestions.

Comment: This question seems more appropriate at [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).  I'm not voting to close because this question is about an algorithm, which is within the terms of the site.  However, you may not get good answers here.

Comment: I think it's more suited for [scicomp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what you know about the matrix.

If the matrix is positive semidefinite, you could use [Cholesky Factorization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438307/factorizing-a-matrix-into-a-matrix-and-its-transpose),
 use pivoting for stability.

Under other assumptions, a solution may not exist.

---

An example where a solution may not exist, there is no solution for the following matrix:

```
[[0, 1],
 [0, 0]]
```

Proof: Assume the answer exists.  Then the solution looks like:

```
L = [[a, b],
     [c, d]]
```

So the following must be True:

1. `a*a + b*c == 0`
2. `d*d + b*c == 0`
3. `c * (a+d) == 0`
4. `b * (a+d) == 1`

According to 3. `(c == 0) or ((a+d) == 0)`

If `c == 0`, then according to 1. and 2. `a == 0` and `d == 0`.  If this is true, then `(a+d) == 0` which makes 4. impossible.

If `(a+d) == 0` then 4. is impossible.

By contradiction we know that there cannot be a decomposition you ask for with this matrix.